# BGE: Change physics attributes of an object in real time. (AKA while playing)

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, logic-bricks, properties

I'm trying to make a boost power up for my video game but I'm terrible at Python and couldn't do it even if my life depended on it. :| Anyway, here's my setup:

I need it so that:

1. The default velocity_max for my object is 50.
2. When the space bar is pressed AND a game property named Boost is greater than 0, change velocity_max to 70.
3. (The property Boost will count down)
4. Once Boost reaches 0 or less, the velocity_max will change back to 50, and can only change back to 70 when (as in #2) spacebar is pressed AND Boost becomes greater than 0 again.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bge

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner
boost = owner["boost"]

if controller.sensors["boost"].positive and controller.sensors["is boostable"].positive:
    owner.linVelocityMax = 7
else:
    owner.linVelocityMax = 2
```

requires two sensors:

- "boost" -> requests to boost
- "is boostable" -> checks if boosting is available

[image]

this does not include counting.

Counting needs a frequent trigger otherwise you count how many times boost was requested, not how long it took. I suggest to add an always sensor with [True Level Triggering]. This way it constantly triggers the controller. The controller is simply an AND controller. There is not need to execute Python all the time.

[image]

For better reading this this is placed at a different state. Make sure both states are enabled when starting the game.

#### Remarks:

I suggest to call the property something like "boost energy" as I guess it should represent some sort of consumed element.

The above system (as you described) is a very easy and simple system assuming t the amount of consumed "boost" is constant. If that is not the case you can indeed create a system that takes away a part of the boost value (immediately reducing the property value) and results in a velocity change. This requires the code to run at each single frame.

I'm not sure if changing the max-velocity can be considered as "boost". The max-velocity applies to all physics calculations inclusive falling.

Comment: This is great! Works like a charm. On a similar note, where did you learn how to code in Python, specifically with the commands and functions Blender uses?

Comment: As funny as it sounds - with the BGE. That was the reason to use Python. (It also helps that I'm working in IT).